# Create a function that returns an array with all the odd numbers from 5 to 118

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

Here's my code, but it's not working. Is my thought-process correct? Please help:

```
function sum_odd(arr) {
   arr = [];
   for (var i = 5; i < 119; i++) {
       if (i % 2 === 1) {
           arr.push(i);
       }
   }
   return arr; 
}
```

Comment: What does not work? Post a demo to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I would use `for (var i = 5; i < 119; i+=2) {...}` as you'll skip the unwanted numbers

Answer (score 6):

Calling `sum_odd()` returns: `[5, 7, 9, 11, 13,..., 117]`

Your code works [fine](https://jsfiddle.net/yom20j5j/) but you don't need the `arr` argument which in fact is not used.

```js
function sum_odd(){
    var arr = [];
    for (var i = 5; i < 119; i++) {
        if (i % 2 === 1) {
            arr.push(i);
        }
    }
    return arr; 
}

var x = sum_odd();
document.write(x);
```

It is a better idea to save half of the loop iterations and do no checks on `i` by [incrementing i by two.](https://jsfiddle.net/yom20j5j/1/)

If you want to modify the argument, remove the `var arr = []` statement.

```js
function sum_odd(arr) {
  for (var i = 5; i < 119; i += 2) {
    arr.push(i);
  }
  return arr;
}

var res = [];
sum_odd(res)
document.write(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue you have is not with the actual code, but the way arguments are passed. When you call `arr=[]`, it does not mutate, or change, the original array to be an empty array.

What it does is it redirects the reference that the function holds--the variable `arr` once held a reference to the parameter passed, but after you assign it to `[]`, it is no longer pointing to the parameter, but it is instead pointing to a new array somewhere else that's initialized to be empty.

So if you run the code

```
array = [];
sum_odd(array);
```

Then the `sum_odd` function does not modify the array passed; instead, it creates a new array and returns it, and in this case the return value isn't used, so `array` remains empty.